# What is the difference between get() and .get in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, get, max

I have these two lines of code in a program

```
res = Counter(test_str)
res = max(res, key=res.get)
```

however, I cannot seem to understand the `key=res.get`. I know that it sorts the keys of the dictionary (res) by the values but I thought the get() method required a mandatory "key" parameter? How can it be just `.get` and not `.get(key=)`?

Comment: `.get(key=)`, the key means the key in the dictionary. Dictionaries are split into key value pairs. If you just pass in an argument without the keyword `key=`, you'll get the same result. the key in the max function takes a function as its key - in this case, the getter function `.get()` for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In the `max` function, the values that you pass in are compared and the highest value is returned. For example, this program returns the highest integer in this list:

```
print(max([1,2,3,4]))
```

However, you can also pass a function into the `key` parameter of `max` which should be a function or lambda that can act on a value in the iterable list and return a value that can be properly compared. For example, the `Counter(stuff).get` method will return an integer for how many times an item appears in a list, if the item is in the list. You can pass in the method rather than the method call to the max function, and the max function will compare the number of times that each individual item shows up in your iterable list. For example:

```
c = Counter('hello, world!')
print(max(c, key=c.get))
```

The example above will print the most common character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The get here is different than the get you are used to i.e. getting data from a dictionary. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) of the function max -

> There are two optional keyword-only arguments. The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort()

What this means is you provide a one-off function that only accepts one argument at max. On the basis of this function, the maximum is going to return the max of the iterator.

For example, changing the key function -

```
from collections import Counter
x = [1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1]
c = Counter(x)
# Counter({1: 7, 2: 2, 3: 2})
max(c, key=lambda x: 1/x) # prints 1 as 1/1 is the largest of c
min(c, key=lambda x: 1/x) # prints 3 is 1/3 is the smallest of c
```

As min also implements the "key" argument. Providing "key" allows the user to change the behaviour of the min/max function.